# can not install gocode in Vscode using WSL

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

when I install gocode in my Vscode using WSL, the error occurs, but in my windows machine, it it ok, and I can install it successfully, Can anyone tell me why, thanks a lot!

[image]

go env

```
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/linux/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/linux/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/linux/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/linux/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build487443134=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: Run the installation as root user (see sudo)

Comment: or install go to some user owned path which will save you also some other hustle. Don't forget to add the path to the go bin to the global path so it can be found by things like vscode.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen yeah, I tried it before, and it works properly, but the go extension can not install it, and there is any method to install it with the extension

Comment: @TheFool I change the mod with `chmod -R 777`, but it still has the problem

Comment: It is possible your go/mod subdirectories have mixed users/rights. Run a chown too to make certain everything is nice and clean.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, it is the network that should be blamed